# Overwrite Interceptor ModelAndView in Spring MVC

Tags: jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I am trying to set a global title for my webpage inside Sring MVC Interceptor posthandle method like so

Interceptor Class

```
model.addObject("title", "global title"); //ModelAndView
```

Then in my controller class I have

```
model.addAttribute("title", "Specific page title"); //Model - Overwrite global title
```

my jsp header

```
<title>${titile}</title>
```

The problem is that I always get the "global title" as a value for the title variable. For some reason, the model ui inside the controller never overwrote the one that being set inside the interceptor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you implement `HandlerInterceptor.postHandle()` method. PostHandle means, this is run after the individual controller has been run. Since you are setting the title attribute *after* the individual handler has tun to "global title", you will always get "global title".

Try HandlerInterceptor.preHandle() - there *is* a chance this would work better I think...

(EDIT: typed nonsense... try *preHandle()*, not try postHandle())

Comment: You are right! Such an obvious mistake -_- and thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: @Infinity how were you able to modify the model in preHandle? I was just looking at the Interceptor interface doc and noticed that modelAndView is only available in the postHandle method.